How can I improve this axios request that returns a blank page?
I am refreshing my fullstack knowledge and have run into a problem with pulling in a single movie from the back end to the front end. When testing via postman I can get the movie without a problem and see all of it's fields. Populating all movies on the front end from the back end is no problem either but I am not sure where the problem is once I go and try to populate just a single movie view after I have populated the first 20.
Here is the route for the single movie view:
 <Route path="/movies/:id/" element={<Movie  user={user} />} />

next is the movie data service where I make the api call

import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/movies";

class MovieDataService {
  async get(id) {
    return axios.get(`${API_URL}/id/${id}`);
  }
}
export default new MovieDataService();


Here is where I try to retrieve a single movie.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MovieDataService from '../services/MovieDataService';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { CardActionArea } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Movie = (props) => {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({
    _id: null,
    title: "",
    rated: "",
    plot: "",
    poster: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovie = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await MovieDataService.get(props.match.params.id);
        setMovie(response.data);
        console.log(response.data); // Log response data to debug
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching movie:', error);
      }
    };

    if (props.match && props.match.params && props.match.params.id) {
      fetchMovie();
    }
  }, [props.match]);

  // Handle loading state or no movie found
  if (!movie.title) {
    return (
      <Container className="Firstset">
        <div>Loading...</div>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container className="Firstset">
      <Row>
        <Col key={movie._id} xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={3}>
          <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                height="345"
                image={movie.poster ? movie.poster + "/345x300" : ""}
                alt={movie.title}
              />
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                  {movie.title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Rated: {movie.rated}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Plot: {movie.plot}
                </Typography>
                <Link to={`/movies/${props.match.params.id}/review`}>Add A review</Link>
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Movie;



After working on it some more I found a solution but I am not sure how to fix the original code: Console.log showed me this  :Warning: React does not recognize the Movie prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase movie instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
. As a result I implemented this code in app.js as a test:
      <Movie match={{ params: { id: '573a1391f29313caabcd6e2a' } }} />


This is now showing me the card exactly as I expect it to, I assume it is because I am adding in the id directly but I am still confused as to how I can fix the original Movie route.

There is a very large amount of code here to walk through.  Can you trim it down to just show the issue?

I trimmed down the code.

What do the browser developer tools tell you?  Are you getting the data back to the browser?  The network tab of the tools should be able to see.  If you are getting the data then it's time to debug a bit.  Pay attention to warnings from your IDE or development environment.  Start with that and let us know how it goes.

'await' is missing, so it runs asynchronously.

I have an await right before the Moviedataservice.get method. Unless I have it in the wrong spot?

Thanks to the both of you for helping me I was able to figure it out.

After 3 days of working on this I figured it out.
First I switched out params id for a hook and then it worked. Now I can successfully get any movie.
const Movie = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams(); // Access id from URL params using useParams hook

  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({
    title: "",
    rated: "",
    plot: "",
    poster: "",
    year: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovie = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await MovieDataService.get(id); // Use id from useParams
        const { title, rated, plot, poster, year } = response.data;
        setMovie({ title, rated, plot, poster, year });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching movie:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchMovie(); // Fetch movie details on component mount
  }, [id]); // Trigger useEffect whenever id changes

  // Handle loading state or no movie found
  if (!movie.title) {
    return (
      <Container className="Firstset">
        <div>Loading...</div>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container className="Firstset">
      <Row>
        <Col key={movie._id} xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={3}>
          <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                height="345"
                image={movie.poster ? movie.poster + "/345x300" : ""}
                alt={movie.title}
              />
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                  {movie.title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Rated: {movie.rated}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Plot: {movie.plot}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Year: {movie.year}
                </Typography>
                <Link to={`/movies/${id}/review`}>Add A review</Link>
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Movie;

